# Insert Error:Incorrect syntax near '@signupDate'

Tags: sql, parameters, insert

I keep getting this error in my sign up page. when i am debugging my system all the parameters are given..when goes inside the for loop it also works..but it enters inside catch and gives me that error..

here is my code..
please help...

```
private void ExecuteInsert(int MerchanttID, int ResellermID, string CompanyName, int AddID,
string streetAdr, string city, string state, int countryID, string zipCode, string TelNum,
string FaxNum, string Url, int IndustryID, Boolean isActive, Boolean isDeleted, 
DateTime DateCreated)
        {
            SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(GetConnectString());

            string merchantQuery = "Insert INTO Merchant_Master (MerchantTypeID,
     ResellerMasterID, CompanyName, AddressID, Url, IndustryID, IsActive, IsDeleted,
     DateCreated) VALUES (@merchantTID, @resellerMID , @CompanyName, @AddID, @website,
     @IDindustry, @Isactive, @IsDeleted, @signupDate"; 

            string addressQuery = "Insert into Address (StreetAdd, City, State, CountryID,
     ZipCode, TelNum, FaxNum) VALUES (@stAd, @CityAdr, @StateAdr, @IDcountry,
     @zCode ,@Tnumb ,@Fnumb)";                                  

            try
            {
                connectionString.Open();

                // Insert Merchant_Master
                SqlCommand merchantCmd = new SqlCommand(merchantQuery, connectionString);
                SqlParameter[] merchant = new SqlParameter[9];

                merchant[0] = new SqlParameter("@merchantTID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                merchant[1] = new SqlParameter("@resellerMID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                merchant[2] = new SqlParameter("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                merchant[3] = new SqlParameter("@AddID", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
                merchant[4] = new SqlParameter("@website", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                merchant[5] = new SqlParameter("@IDindustry", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
                merchant[6] = new SqlParameter("@Isactive", SqlDbType.Bit, 100);
                merchant[7] = new SqlParameter("@IsDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit, 100);
                merchant[8] = new SqlParameter("@signupDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0);

                merchant[0].Value = MerchanttID;
                merchant[1].Value = ResellermID;
                merchant[2].Value = CompanyName;
                merchant[3].Value = AddID;
                merchant[4].Value = Url;
                merchant[5].Value = IndustryID;
                merchant[6].Value = isActive;
                merchant[7].Value = isDeleted;
                merchant[8].Value = DateTime.Now;

                for (int i = 0; i < merchant.Length; i++)
                {
                    merchantCmd.Parameters.Add(merchant[i]);
                }
                merchantCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                merchantCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Insert Address
                SqlCommand addressCmd = new SqlCommand(addressQuery, connectionString);
                SqlParameter[] address = new SqlParameter[7];

                address[0] = new SqlParameter("@stAd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                address[1] = new SqlParameter("@CityAdr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                address[2] = new SqlParameter("@StateAdr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                address[3] = new SqlParameter("@IDcountry", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
                address[4] = new SqlParameter("@zCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                address[5] = new SqlParameter("@Tnumb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                address[6] = new SqlParameter("@Fnumb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

                address[0].Value = streetAdr;
                address[1].Value = city;
                address[2].Value = state;
                address[3].Value = countryID;
                address[4].Value = zipCode;
                address[5].Value = TelNum;
                address[6].Value = FaxNum;

                for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
                {
                    addressCmd.Parameters.Add(address[i]);
                }
                addressCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                addressCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = "Insert Error:";
                errorMsg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(errorMsg);
            }
            finally 
            {
                connectionString.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void Submitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int AdrID = 0;
            Boolean isactive = true;
            Boolean isdeleted = false;

            ExecuteInsert ( int.Parse(drpR.SelectedValue),
                            int.Parse(drpT.SelectedValue),
                            CompanyName.Text,
                            AdrID,
                            stADR.Text,
                            City.Text,
                            State.Text,
                            int.Parse(drpC.SelectedValue),
                            Zcode.Text,
                            TNumber.Text,
                            FNumber.Text,
                            Url.Text,
                            int.Parse(drpI.SelectedValue),
                            isactive,
                            isdeleted,
                            DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: It looks like `Java JDBC`, is it? If I'm right, please add the tag to your question.

Comment: Please post the error/exception itself with full trace back (if available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a closing parentheses on your merchantQuery string.